# How to maintain the size of a div through jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
$('.invoice_resend').hide();
$('.invoice_resend #update_paid').hide(); 
$('.invoice_send').hide();
```

So i have this code above, class `invoice_resend` is a div, which when a button is clicked will be hidden as shown above, and the `#update_paid` and `.invoice_send` too will be hidden, leaving me with a "**RESIZED DIV**" element.

What i want is that when all other elements are hidden, the `.invoice_resend div` will maintain its height or whatever needs to be edited.

**EDIT:**

Ok here is my whole code:

```
if (selected_tab == 0) { //Released tab


$('.invoice_resend').hide();
$('.invoice_send').show();
}
else if ( selected_tab == 1 ) { //Invoiced tab


$('.invoice_resend').show();
$('.invoice_resend #update_paid').show(); 
$('.invoice_send').hide();
}
else if ( selected_tab == 2 ) { //Paid tab


$('.invoice_resend').show();
$('.invoice_resend #update_paid').hide(); 
$('.invoice_send').hide();
}
else if ( selected_tab == 3 ) { //Pending tab


$('.invoice_resend').hide();
$('.invoice_resend #update_paid').hide(); 
$('.invoice_send').hide();
}
```

Seems like the `css.({visibility: 'hidden' or 'visible'})` did the job but generated another problem. You see, I have several tabs, so when i click on the last tab which i hide all the elements, it will become unstable, showing or hiding random elements when i click on another tab. The above code is my original code, which i edited all to .css based on your answers.

Comment: Can you post all your `JQuery`code, or make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: instead of hiding just set their visibility to hidden. In that case all the hidden divs will have their height and parent or wrapper div will also maintain their height. Secondly solution will be to give fixed height to your wrapper div.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `show()`  `hide()`

use css properties

```
visibility:visible; 

visibility:hidden;
```

A [sample demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VwjxJ/) found here.

If you check,event the element have it's `height` there even not `visible`.

Comment: can i do something like this?  $('.invoice_resend').css({ visibility: hidden});

Comment: @BelmarkCaday Yes.Go ahead  :)And `''`  missing for `hidden` :)

Comment: Instead of direct `css` , I would like to suggest to prepare two css classes and do add and remove class.Those classes will be useful further.

Comment: Can you please make a demo fiddle? which describes your problem clearly?

Comment: they are just 4 tabs, which show or hide different buttons depending on which tab is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.invoice_resend #update_paid').css({ visibility: 'hidden' });
```

From the MDN docs:

```
    The visibility CSS property has two purposes:

 1. The hidden value hides an element but leaves space where it would
    have been.

 2. The collapse value hides rows or columns of a table. It also
    collapses XUL elements.
```

For the edited question:

```
if (selected_tab == 0) { //Released tab


$('.invoice_resend').hide();
$('.invoice_send').show();
}
else if ( selected_tab == 1 ) { //Invoiced tab


$('.invoice_resend').show();
$('.invoice_resend #update_paid').css({ visibility: 'visible' }); 
$('.invoice_send').hide();
}
else if ( selected_tab == 2 ) { //Paid tab


$('.invoice_resend').show();
$('.invoice_resend #update_paid').css({ visibility: 'hidden' }); 
$('.invoice_send').hide();
}
else if ( selected_tab == 3 ) { //Pending tab


$('.invoice_resend').hide();
$('.invoice_resend #update_paid').css({ visibility: 'hidden' }); 
$('.invoice_send').hide();
}
```

Comment: is the updated answer what you need ? because i do not really understand the problem now. You've confused me :)

Answer (score 0):

just make another div and put invoice_resend div inside it and in css set parent div's width and height.

Answer (score 0):

you could also extend jQuery to make your own show / hide class, and dicide there what to do:

```
jQuery.fn.myShow = function() {
    var o = $(this[0]); 
    o.addClass("show").removeClass("hide");
};
jQuery.fn.myHide = function() {
    var o = $(this[0]);
    o.addClass("hide").removeClass("show");
};

$('.invoice_resend').myHide();

.hide {
    visibility:hidden; 
}
```